# Create ACL for exim4 to block certain Domains

Tags: exim4

I setup the following rule in Exim, but mails from qq.com still passing through. What is my mistake?  I saw similar answers giving this example for exim, but in my case it is not working (Ubuntu 20.04, exim 4.93)

exim4.conf:

domainlist deny_sender = /etc/exim4/deny_sender

...

begin acl

acl_check_sender:

deny
domains = +deny_sender
message = Mail rejected; Sender denied

/etc/exim4/deny_sender:

*@qq.com
.*@qq.com

I tried as well:

deny    condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim4/deny_senders}{yes}}
message = Mail reject; Sender denied

did not work either.

Frank